# twillio - make a search by city or region

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

How can I make the search by location.
https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/search
In their example there is a way to search by location e.g. Boston, also it is possible to search by region.
Here is their example:

```
$numbers = $client->account->available_phone_numbers->getList('US', 'Local', array(
        "InRegion" => "AR"
    ));
```

How can I make a search by region  or by city as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are a bunch of advanced filters you can use to search for numbers in the US and Canada.

`InRegion`, as you left as an example, is one of the filters. The rest can be seen here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers#local-get-advanced-filters

To get a city based search, you could combine a geolocation lookup on the name of the city, to get the latitude and longitude, and the `NearLatLong` and `Distance` filters to get something near the city.

Hope that helps!